# How to convert string 2021-09-30_1 to datetime

Tags: python, date

How can I convert string 2021-09-30_1 to datetime 2021/09/30 00:00, which means that from the last string we have to substract one to get the hour.

I tried `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y %d %Y %I')`

Comment: there is something fundamentally unclear, does the `_1` specify the hour or a delta?

Comment: Hi, it is the hour, but added by one: _1 means hour 00:00, _22 means hour 21:00, _3 means hour 02:00

Comment: OK, this wasn't clear, please edit the question to add an explicit example, what you want is what @MSH suggested

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.strptime` if to define the timestamp from a string, the format should match the provided one. `datetime.strftime` (note the **f**) is to generate a string from a datetime object.
You can use:

```
datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d_%H').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

output: `'2021/09/30 01:00'`

##### in case the `_x` defines a delta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d, h = date.split('_')
d = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
h = timedelta(hours=int(h))
(d-h).strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

output: `'2021/09/29 23:00'`

Comment: But this 1 corresponds to an hour, for example if 1 was 22, the hour should be 21:00

Comment: @ryszardeggink sorry this wasn't clear, check the update

Comment: But why 21h for 22?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the `_1` is hour and appears in al of your data (The hour part takes value between [1, 24]), your format was wrong.

For reading the date from string you'll need format it correctly:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = "2021-09-30_1"

date_part, hour_part = date.split("_")
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_part, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(hours=int(hour_part) - 1)
```

Now you have the date object. And you can display it as:

```
print(date_object.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))
```

Comment: Hi, it is not redundant, it defines the hour for example _22 says it should be hour 21:00, _1 means hour 0:00.

Comment: Answer is edited.

Comment: Thank you, what if the H is exactly 24 ? it seems to produce an error

Comment: Yes. You're right. Now we must split the data by `_`. I did another update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

raw_date = "2021-09-30_1"
date = raw_date.split("_")[0]
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
formated_date = parsed_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

[strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is used for parsing string and [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) for formating.

Also for date representation you should provide [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for hours and minutes as in:

`formated_date = parsed_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')`